# Why isin't the vector able to hold all 52 elements?

Tags: vector

I have a program where I use a vector to simulate all the possible outcomes when counting cards in blackjack. There's only three possible values, -1, 0, and 1. There's 52 cards in a deck therefore the vector will have 52 elements, each assigned one of values mentioned above. The program works when I scale down the size of the vector, it still works when I have it as this size however I get no output and get the warning "warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data".

```
#include<iostream>
#include"subtracter.h"
#include<time.h>
#include<vector>
#include<random>
using namespace std;

int acecard = 4;
int twocard = 4;
int threecard = 4;
int fourcard = 4;
int fivecard = 4;
int sixcard = 4;
int sevencard = 4;
int eightcard = 4;
int ninecard = 4;
int tencard = 16;
// declares how many of each card there is 

vector<int> cardvalues = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
// a vector that describes how many cards there are with a certain value
vector<int> deck = { acecard, twocard, threecard, fourcard, fivecard, sixcard, sevencard, eightcard, ninecard, tencard };
// a vector keeping track of how many of each cards there's left in the deck


int start()
{
    int deckcount;
    deckcount = 0;
    int decksize;
    decksize = cardvalues.size();
    while (decksize >= 49)
    {

        deckcount += cardsubtracter(cardvalues);
    };

    return deckcount;
}

int cardcounting()
{
    int deckcount;
    deckcount = start();
    deckcount += cardsubtracter(cardvalues);
    return deckcount;
}



int main()
{
    int value;
    value = cardcounting();
    int size;
    size = cardvalues.size();
    cout << value << "\n";
    cout << size;
    return 0;
}


#include<iostream>
#include<random>
using namespace std;



int numbergenerator(int x, int y)
{
    int number;
    random_device generator;
    uniform_int_distribution<>distrib(x, y);
    number = distrib(generator); //picks random element from vector
    return number;
}
int cardsubtracter(vector<int> mynum)
{
    int counter;
    int size;
    int number;
    size = mynum.size() - 1;//gives the range of values to picked from the vectorlist
    number = numbergenerator(0, size);//gives a random number to pick from the vectorlist

    counter = mynum[number]; // uses the random number to pick a value from the vectorlist
    mynum.erase(mynum.begin()+number); //removes that value from the vectorlist

    return counter;
}
```

I looked up the max limit of vectors and it said that vectors can hold up 232 values with integers, which should work for this. So I also tried creating a new file and copying the code over to that in case there was something wrong with this file.

Answer (score 0):

There could be different reasons why a vector may not be able to hold all 52 elements. Some possible reasons are:

Insufficient memory: Each element in a vector requires a certain amount of memory, and the total memory required for all 52 elements may exceed the available memory. This can happen if the elements are large, or if there are many other variables or data structures in the environment that consume memory.

Data type limitations: The data type of the vector may not be able to accommodate all 52 elements. For example, if the vector is of type "integer", it can only hold integers up to a certain limit, beyond which it will overflow or produce incorrect results.

Code errors: There may be errors in the code that prevent all 52 elements from being added to the vector. For example, if the vector is being filled in a loop, there may be a mistake in the loop condition or in the indexing that causes the loop to terminate early or skip some elements.

To determine the exact reason for the vector not being able to hold all 52 elements, it is necessary to examine the code, the data types involved, and the memory usage.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).